# How to use presentModalViewController to create a transparent view

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am displaying a modal view with

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

When the view moves up the screen it is transparent as per the setting in the xib file it is created from, but once it fills the screen it goes opaque.

Is there anyway of keeping the view transparent?

I suspect that the view it is being placed over is not being rendered rather then that the modal view is becoming opaque.

Comment: This question is now pretty old.  When looking for answers look for one that applies to the version of iOS that you use.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/q/27598846/1603234 make me smile, now your turn :)

Comment: you can use `viewcontroller.modalPresentationStyle = .FormSheet`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your view is still transparent, but once your modal controller is at the top of the stack, the view behind it is hidden (as is the case with any top-most view controller). The solution is to manually animate a view yourself; then the behind-viewController won't be hidden (since you won't have 'left' it).

Comment: Thanks,  that confirms what I suspected.

Comment: I've filed a bug report with Apple about this issue. Open Radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1062402

Comment: Problem with this is the presented view can't have its own autorotation settings.

Answer (score 85):

After iOS 3.2 there is a method to do this without any “tricks” – [see the documentation for the modalPresentationStyle property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationStyle). You have a rootViewController which will present the viewController.
So here's the code to success:

```
viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[rootViewController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

With this method the viewController's background will be transparent and the underlying rootViewController will be visible. *Please note that this only seems to work on the iPad,* see comments below.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Please consider adding more explanation, your way seems more clean and future proof.

Comment: You should check the documentation and check the modalPresentationStyle property. Please do it and answer here. Thank you!

Comment: Hi.. +1 from my side bcoz it works fine in iOS 4 and iPad. but how it will work in iPhone 3.0. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! On iPhone 3.0 it will not work, because the documentation says that it is working from iOS 3.2 and iOS 3.2 as I know it was for iPad 1 first release.

Comment: If you can manage to work with your configuration, please share your experience with us. Thank you!

Comment: Had initial problem, but now working just fine. I set the modalPresentationStyle on MY view not the root view. Ugh. Working fine now. How do I undo the -1 ? (sorry :-( )

Comment: Hmmm - interesting difference. I was hoping to animate a picker up (along with other views). What's happening now is that the animation is gone - the picker just appears. I tried setting/unsetting the modalPresentationStyle, and when its UIModalPresentationCurrentContext the view just appears - when I comment out that line the new view slides up then the "rootView' disappears. However, I can of course animate the picker myself. I tried this in the 4.3 Simulator and in a newer unreleased one - no change.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tried with animation. You can undo -1 by clicking the down arrow again. Also if you found the solution with animation, please let as know about it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not working for me (iOS 5.0), can someone show some code?

Comment: Hello guys you need a small change set modalPresentationStyle to viewController instead of rootView controller

Comment: This does not appear to work on iPhone/iPod, only iPad (see documentation linked in the answer). @simpleBob: maybe this is why it's not working for you?

Comment: It's not working on iOS 5.1, already read the documentation and doesn't give much additional details.

Comment: This solution seems to work nicely. However the issue I have noticed is that if you rotate the device it will correctly rotate the modal view, however the underlying view doesn't get rotated. Anyone else faced this issue? Got a solution?!

Comment: FYI: I have asked the same question in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419395/ios-apply-view-rotation-to-view-controller-under-modal-view

Comment: Note the **root** ViewController. Works with a `rootViewController`, but I cannot get this to work with any other UIViewController (iOS 7).

Comment: In iOS 7, use self.view.superview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];  in presented view controller seems work.

Comment: While this works, iOS does it's darndest to undo it. Pushing or popping view controllers on the navigation controller will undo everything.

Comment: I tested on iOS 8, and I have to use `Over Current Context` as presentation style.

Answer (score 48):

What I needed to get this to work:

```
self.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Comment: it simple works , thanks i just kept my code on - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method and voila

Comment: You can also just set the `modalPresentationStyle` on the presenting view controller (instead of on the window's `rootViewController`).

Comment: Thanks!! even works when you do, [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"open" sender:self];

Comment: You can always animate the view by hand in viewdidload of the modal.

Comment: Note that, as Mr. T said below, the modalPresentationStyle has to be set on the view controller that currently has the full screen.

Comment: Since iOS 8, you have to set UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext on the view controller being presented (see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26891602)

Answer (score 24):

For those who want to see some code, here's what I added to my transparent view's controller:

```
// Add this view to superview, and slide it in from the bottom
- (void)presentWithSuperview:(UIView *)superview {
    // Set initial location at bottom of superview
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, superview.bounds.size.height);
    self.view.frame = frame;
    [superview addSubview:self.view];            

    // Animate to new location
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"presentWithSuperview" context:nil];
    frame.origin = CGPointZero;
    self.view.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

// Method called when removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation's animation completes
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID
                finished:(NSNumber *)finished
                 context:(void *)context {
    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation"]) {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

// Slide this view to bottom of superview, then remove from superview
- (void)removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation" context:nil];

    // Set delegate and selector to remove from superview when animation completes
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    // Move this view to bottom of superview
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, self.view.superview.bounds.size.height);
    self.view.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];    
}
```

Comment: The only problem I have with this solution is memory management.
For example:
TestViewController *testView = [[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestView" bundle:nil];
[testView presentWithSuperview:self.navigationController.view];

Will work fine, however if you attempt to release or autorelease the View, any calls to methods within that view, will result in bad access exceptions

Comment: Are you sure? I think the view will be retained by [superview addSubview:], so you should be able to release it.

Comment: If you call presentWithSuperview then release testView it crashes. It also displays displays "under" any NavigationController toolbars etc.

Comment: This has worked fine for me for a long time, but it no longer works in landscape mode. Anyone have this same issue?

Answer (score 19):

The Apple-approved way to do this in iOS 8 is to set the modalPresentationStyle to 'UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext'.

From the UIViewController documentation:

> **UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext**
>
> A presentation style where the content is displayed over only the
>   parent view controller’s content. The views beneath the presented
>   content are not removed from the view hierarchy when the presentation
>   finishes. So if the presented view controller does not fill the screen
>   with opaque content, the underlying content shows through.
>
> When presenting a view controller in a popover, this presentation
>   style is supported only if the transition style is
>   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical. Attempting to use a different
>   transition style triggers an exception. However, you may use other
>   transition styles (except the partial curl transition) if the parent
>   view controller is not in a popover.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/

The 'View Controller Advancements in iOS 8' video from WWDC 2014 goes into this in some detail.

Be sure to give your presented view controller a clear background color (otherwise, it will still appear opaque).

Comment: it gives me a black screen on iOS8 and iOS9

Comment: Actually it works if you set your view controller's view a background color with an alpha value below 1

Answer (score 16):

There is another option: before showing the modal controller, capture a screenshot of the whole window. Insert the captured image into an UIImageView and add the image view to the controller's view you're about to show.
Then send to back.
Insert another view above the image view (background black, alpha 0.7).
Show your modal controller and it looks like it was transparent.
Just tried it on iPhone 4 running iOS 4.3.1. Like charm.

Comment: good one, i implement this it was great for me.add my code which follow this concept.

Comment: Nobody said it's going to be easy! :-)

Comment: How would you support device rotation with this approach?

Answer (score 10):

this is quite old, but i solved the same problem as follows:
Since i need to present a navigation controller in iPhone, adding a subview wasn't a viable solution.

So what i did:

1) Before presenting the view controller, take a screenshot of your current screen:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

2) Create the view controller you want to present, and add the background as a subview, sending it to back.

```
UIViewController * presentingVC = [UIViewController new];
UIImageView * backgroundImageOfPreviousScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
[presentingVC.view addSubview:backgroundImageOfPreviousScreen];
[presentingVC.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageOfPreviousScreen];
```

3) Present your view controller, but before that in the new view controller, add a transparent view in the viewDidLoad (i used ILTranslucentView)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ILTranslucentView * translucentView = [[ILTranslucentView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:translucentView];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:translucentView];
}
```

And that's all!

Comment: Awesome. All worked well beside the translucent view which caused the screen shot disappearance.

Comment: This is a great solution!  It is better for keeping the controller code for the popup separate from the parent view controller.

Comment: For me worked but setting background had to be in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 5):

I wrote down my findings about this in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079501/588253), but the gist of it is that you have to call `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` on whatever owns the full screen at the moment.  Most of the time, it's whatever is the [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window's rootViewController.  It could also be a new UIViewController that was presented with `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.

Please read my other much more detailed post if you're wondering how I specifically solved this problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be broken in IOS 8, I am using a navigation controller and the context that is being displayed is the Navigation menus context which in our case is a sliding Menu controller.

We are using  pod 'TWTSideMenuViewController', '0.3' have not checked to see if this is an issue with the library yet or the method described above.

Answer (score 5):

This worked to me in iOS 8-9:

1- Set your view controller's background with an alpha

2- add this code:

```
TranslucentViewController *tvc = [[TranslucentViewController alloc] init];
self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[tvc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:tvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is pretty old question. I was stuck on this issue and I was able to get a lead from this thread. So putting here how I got it worked :) .
I am using storyboard and I have  segue to the ViewController which is to be presented. The view controller have a transparent background colour. Now in the Attributes inspector of the segue I set the presentation to "Over current context".And it worked for me. I am developing for iPhone. 
[image: Attributes Inspector of the segue]

Comment: thanks, also works by set UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext programmatically

Answer (score 3):

In my condition i am having view on same viewController. So make a new view controller for holding UIView. Make that view transparent by setting it's alpha property.
Then on a button click i wrote this code. It looks good.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(objAppDelegate.window.frame.size);
    [objAppDelegate.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    UIViewController *controllerForBlackTransparentView=[[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [controllerForBlackTransparentView setView:viewForProfanity];

    UIImageView *imageForBackgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 480)];
    [imageForBackgroundView setImage:viewImage];

    [viewForProfanity insertSubview:imageForBackgroundView atIndex:0];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controllerForBlackTransparentView animated:YES];
```

And it shows what i want. hope it help some one.

Answer (score 3):

I've created open soruce library [MZFormSheetController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController) to present modal form sheet on additional UIWindow. You can use it to present transparency modal view controller, even adjust the size of the presented view controller.

Comment: Can you explain how to use it? Because when I try to invoke the code it cause SIGABRT.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a category I've created that will solve the problem.

```
    //
    //  UIViewController+Alerts.h
    //

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface UIViewController (Alerts)

    - (void)presentAlertViewController:(UIViewController *)alertViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
    - (void)dismissAlertViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;

    @end


    //
    //  UIViewController+Alerts.m
    //

    #import "UIViewController+Alerts.h"

    @implementation UIViewController (Alerts)

    - (void)presentAlertViewController:(UIViewController *)alertViewController animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
            // Setup frame of alert view we're about to display to just off the bottom of the view
            [alertViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, alertViewController.view.frame.size.width, alertViewController.view.frame.size.height)];

            // Tag this view so we can find it again later to dismiss
            alertViewController.view.tag = 253;

            // Add new view to our view stack
            [self.view addSubview:alertViewController.view];

            // animate into position
            [UIView animateWithDuration:(animated ? 0.5 : 0.0) animations:^{
                    [alertViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - alertViewController.view.frame.size.height) / 2, alertViewController.view.frame.size.width, alertViewController.view.frame.size.height)];
            }];      
    }

    - (void)dismissAlertViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
    {
            UIView *alertView = nil;

            // find our tagged view
            for (UIView *tempView in self.view.subviews)
            {
                    if (tempView.tag == 253)
                    {
                            alertView = tempView;
                            break;
                    }
            }

            if (alertView)
            {
                    // clear tag
                    alertView.tag = 0;

                    // animate out of position
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:(animated ? 0.5 : 0.0) animations:^{
                            [alertView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, alertView.frame.size.width, alertView.frame.size.height)];
                    }];      
            }
    }

    @end
```

Comment: FYI, no need to loop through the subviews on your own in the dismiss method. The framework will do it for you with [self.view viewWithTag:253];

Comment: Dave Wood's category on this example displays your view as-is. So you must also set your background of your xib's view's Alpha setting to lower than 1 to get the translucent effect.

Comment: This category has a problem when presenting over a scrollable view such as a table view: Scrolling works. That's bad. The user can scroll the presented view off-screen. The underlying presenting view's contents come onto the screen.

Comment: I've since updated this category.  You can get the code here: https://gist.github.com/4423365.  I use it over table views and collection views without the scrolling problem you describe.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research looks like this will solve our issue and serve our purpose.

create a segue from source VC to destination VC with an identifier.

for example "goToDestinationViewController"
okay to makes lives easy let's consider the current view controller i.e, the one you want behind your transparent view as source and the destination as destination

Now in source VC in viewDidLoad: or view

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDestinationViewController", sender: nil)
```

good  we are half way through.
Now go to your storyboard. Click on the segue. which should look like this:
[segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwkOn.png)

change the options to what are shown.

Now comes the real solution.

in your destination view controller's viewDidLoad add this code.

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
```

.........................................................................THAT EASY..................................................................

Comment: Setting `self.modalPresentationStyle = .custom` works for me in modally presenting an actual view controller with a transparent background in Swift 3, Xcode 8. The only issue is that if the presenting view controller is embedded in a tab bar controller, the tab bar shows up in front of the transparent background view.

Comment: So—if a tab bar is in use—the presenting view controller's `tabBarController.tabBar.isHidden` should then be set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way is to use a "container view". Just make alpha below 1 and embed with seque.
XCode 5, target iOS7.

can't show image, not enough reputation)))

Container view available from iOS6.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine on iPhone under iOS6 and iOS7:

```
presentedVC.view.backgroundColor = YOUR_COLOR; // can be with 'alpha'
presentingVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[presentingVC presentViewController:presentedVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But along this way you loose 'slide-from-the-bottom' animation.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on iPhone. The underneath view still disappears. I believe modalPresentationStyle only applies to iPad.

Comment: If you want I can send you screens of the resulting effect.
Maybe something is wrong with your implementation.

Comment: Ah... it was because I wasn't aware that the view controller has to be full screen. (See Mr. T's comment.)

Answer (score 1):

I found this elegant and simple solution for iOS 7 and above!

For iOS 8 Apple added UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext, but it does not work for iOS 7 and prior, so I could not use it for my case.

Please, create the category and put the following code.

.h file

```
typedef void(^DismissBlock)(void);

@interface UIViewController (Ext)

- (DismissBlock)presentController:(UIViewController *)controller
              withBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color
                         andAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha
                presentCompletion:(void(^)(void))presentCompletion;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "UIViewController+Ext.h"

@implementation UIViewController (Ext)

- (DismissBlock)presentController:(UIViewController *)controller
              withBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color
                         andAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha
                presentCompletion:(void(^)(void))presentCompletion
{
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

    UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    __block UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:keyWindow.bounds];
    if (color == nil) {
        color = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    overlay.backgroundColor = color;
    overlay.alpha = alpha;

    if (self.navigationController != nil) {
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlay];
    }
    else if (self.tabBarController != nil) {
        [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:overlay];
    }
    else {
        [self.view addSubview:overlay];
    }

    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:controller
                       animated:true
                     completion:presentCompletion];

    DismissBlock dismissBlock = ^(void) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                         animations:^{
                             overlay.alpha = 0;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [overlay removeFromSuperview];
                         }];
    };
    return dismissBlock;
}

@end
```

Note: it works also for navigationContoller, tabBarController.

Example of usage:

```
       // Please, insure that your controller has clear background
       ViewController *controller = [ViewController instance];
        __block DismissBlock dismissBlock = [self presentController:controller
                                                withBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]
                                                           andAlpha:0.5
                                                  presentCompletion:nil];
        // Supposed to be your controller's closing callback
        controller.dismissed = ^(void) {
            dismissBlock();
        };
```

Enjoy it! and please, leave some feedbacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and cleanest way I found so far:

```
@protocol EditLoginDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)dissmissEditLogin;

@end

- (IBAction)showtTransparentView:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"foo bar"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:@"destructive"
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet{

    UIStoryboard *loginStoryboard     = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    self.editLoginViewController      = [loginStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditLoginViewController"];

    self.editLoginViewController.delegate = self;

    [self.editLoginViewController viewWillAppear:NO];
    [actionSheet addSubview:self.editLoginViewController.view];
    [self.editLoginViewController viewDidAppear:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have come across is to use the addChildViewController method.
Here is an excellent example : [Add a child view controller's view to a subview of the parent view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011579/add-a-child-view-controllers-view-to-a-subview-of-the-parent-view-controller)

Answer (score 0):

I try to use multiple methods to solve but still failed, the follow code implemented finally.

The resolution by Swift:

```
// A.swift init method
modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext // or overCurrentContent
modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve // dissolve means overlay
```

then in B view controller：

```
// B.swift
let a = A()
self.present(a, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You have to make the ViewController 's view 's backgroundColor to be transparent too. 


 view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear