# How to remove split second white screen between dismissing a view controller and loading a new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm using this to dismiss the view controller.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
self.view.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0
                 animations:^{self.parentViewController.view.alpha  = 1.0;}];
self.parentViewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
```

But it is still displaying the white screen before it displays the view controller and I have even changed all my components to a different colour to see if it was a component but the screen stayed white.

Comment: gone through this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741224/ios-modal-viewcontroller-with-transparent-background

Answer (score 0):

check out this code:-

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentModalViewController:modalVC animated:YES];
```