# ModalViewController transparent background iOS 8

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8, modalviewcontroller

Opened old project in Xcode 6 and found issue that background is not transparent in presented view controller. I have used solution in the topic below and it worked so far in ios7.
[iOS : ModalView with background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760698/ios-modalview-with-background-transparent)

Please advice how to deal with iOS 8.

Comment: Check [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27175632/817598) for a solution that works in both iOS 7 and 8

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try setting the modalPresentationStyle property of the **presented** view controller to the new *UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext* constant e.g.

```
[_modalViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext]
```

Comment: If you changed presentation style in "segue", you have to change it back to default. or it will give you a black background.

Comment: what about in code? I set this presentation style and still get it :/ I am calling presentViewController

Comment: If you have a tab bar, use Full Screen instead.

Answer (score 19):

mmccomb's solution eventually worked for me, but I had to tweak a couple of things. Hopefully these details help someone:

1) I had to set the property of the presented view controller from the presenting view controller, like this:

```
MyViewController *myVc = [segue destinationViewController];
[myVc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
```

Setting the presentation style from within the presented VC's viewDidLoad didn't work.

2) I was using a storyboard, and I had to go into the segue properties and set the Presentation style to Default. Setting any other value gave me a black background.

Comment: Setting presentation style in viewDidLoad didn't work for me either, it must be reset somewhere else.

Comment: I think that's another xcode's bug, 2) works for me!

Comment: slightly different in swift: `myVc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext`, rest exactly the same as in this answer! +1

Answer (score 16):

## Interface Builder Solution

Thanks to @mmccomb's programmatic solution.

### Achieve this by:

1. **Creating a segue** in your storyboard file (ctrl + click & drag)
2. Choosing **Present Modally** from the dropdown options
3. **Select the Modal Segue** in the IB Storyboard - *(just the segue)*
4. Set **Presentation** in the *Attributes Inspector* to **Over Current Context**

I would recommend changing the alpha/opacity to 50% + and using a darker background color, otherwise you'll have a hard time distinguishing between the presenting view controller's content and the one you are presenting modally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and the steps you give. This is exactly what i'm looking for.

Comment: @ChrisHaze, I follow these steps you give I have solved my issue but when dismiss view controller previous view controller's view's methods didn't call like viewWillAppear of viewDidAppear etc. why ?

Answer (score 4):

If you changed presentation style in "segue", you have to change it back to default. or it will give you a black background.

I've tried using Storyboard with Segue config, however it does not work.

here is the code works for me, in the `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method:

```c
// Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PresentStationChooserViewController"])
{
    ChooseStationViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    controller.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.7f];
    [controller setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
    controller.stationList = _remoteStations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**iOS8+**

Please take a look on below code snippet, its solved my problem,

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;           
[self presentViewController:secondViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```