# Best Solution for display transparent modal view controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to display the modal view controller when button is clicked.I added the following code for show the dialog

```
Login *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];        
self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Where ***Login*** is the class name.But it doesn't worked for me.

And i am following this link [Display clearColor UIViewController over UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller/11252969#11252969..This) solution also didnt work.
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate that **didn't work** part ?

Comment: Have you tried things like [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal)...?

Comment: @Bhavin still the modal view controller displays with black color background instead of displays as transparent

Comment: Try to set [UIColor clearColor] to navigationController also.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I have the same implementation . Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

"*NOTICE: The bad news is that the above solution doesn't work on iOS 7. The good news is that I fixed the issue for iOS7! via https://stackoverflow.com/a/11252969/1344459*"

You may see my solution for the above issue in iOS7: https://github.com/hightech/iOS-7-Custom-ModalViewController-Transitions

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do that is using blurry modal segue.

https://github.com/Citrrus/BlurryModalSegue

Answer (score 0):

Use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949734/2066428

It works great on iOS7 also. Note that it also works on iPhone while someone doubt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom UIViewController transitions with iOS 7 to do what you want.

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/