# Add UITableView (outside of ViewController) as UIWindow subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am working with a custom view class that is NOT in a `UIViewController`.  Based on the text entered into the text field of my custom view, I want to present a `UITableView` over the rest of the screen (nevermind frame size concerns).

This behavior is identical to what happens when you start tagging someone in a post on Facebook or Twitter, starting with the @ sign: A table view is presented with a list of users that you can select to tag.

So, from a view (not viewController), how can I present a `UITableView` on top of the parent view that my custom view is displayed in?  Is my only option to do this by adding a `UITableView` to the `UIWindow`?  If so, how?  I've read all the questions related to that, and none of them address my concerns.

Comment: a view is never a view controller

Comment: I'm aware of that.  I'm just pointing this out because all the other possible duplicate questions users might claim here, are referring to viewControllers, not views.

Comment: BTW: from what I understand you should stick with UIViewControllers. Using containment.

Comment: Intentionally being redundant doesn't mean I'm unaware.  Just telling me to stick with a VC isn't going to solve my issue.

Comment: well, taking the words "uiviewcontroller" and "containment" and ask google would solve it.

Comment: or simply check the the docs for `presentViewController:animated:` and transition delegate to create a transparent background.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741224/ios-modal-viewcontroller-with-transparent-background

Comment: though presenting would mean it would take over the whole screen. go with containment.

Comment: Add the table view as a subview to your custom view and make sure that clipsToBounds is false for your custom view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; //create object of your AppDelegate

UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)]; //set your desired frame
[delegate.window addSubview:tableView];
tableView.layer.zPosition = 1; //table will appear on top of your screen
```

I have checked it, its working, so hope it helps