# Is there a way to prevent modal view to take fullscreen on iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift

I know this is an iPhone thing that the ViewController will take fullscreen when presented modally (in iPad it has transparent layer and not fullscreen). But is there a possible way to prevent the ViewController getting fullscreen on iPhone? I found some third party libraries that claim to do it but I'm hoping there's a way to do it without a third party library.

Comment: You might create a controller with a clear background then add a view on top that is sized however you like: [ios-modal-viewcontroller-with-transparent-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741224/ios-modal-viewcontroller-with-transparent-background)

Comment: @Joe yeah that's one of the option I found over the net.

Comment: @Joe, can you add your comment as "answer" so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create a controller with a clear background then add a view on top that is sized however you like:

[iOS: Modal ViewController with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741224/ios-modal-viewcontroller-with-transparent-background)