# Modal presentation Controller with transparent background

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

how to remove the default gray colour when change detent in modal presentation from medium to large ? [image]

I need to remove this gray colour attached in above image while drag page sheet or move it I need to make it Transparent colour while moving modal  to be like this when move from medium detent to large one

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: Modal ViewController with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741224/ios-modal-viewcontroller-with-transparent-background)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UISheetPresentationController` to present. You can look at [`largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier`](https://doc://com.apple.documentation/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontroller/3858107-largestundimmeddetentidentifier?language=swift).

If you set that variable to `.large` your medium detent will have no dimmed background.

```
if let sheet = vc.sheetPresentationController {
    sheet.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
    sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
    sheet.selectedDetentIdentifier = .medium
    sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
    sheet.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true
    sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .large
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should have to set the view background color to be `clear` before presenting the modal

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
self.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: he is talking about using sheetPresentationController