# Segue Modal transition removes source controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I have a simple structure hooked up in Storyboard. I want to transition from one scene to another using a Modal transition. The scene where I am transitioning to is smaller then the current scene. So I want the "bounds" of the current scene to be visible behind the modal view.

[image: My basic setup]
[image: Segue settings]

But when I transition, and the transition is completed, the source view controller is removed from screen. Leaving black surroundings behind.

I have made a short video with the problem. Which can be found [here](http://cl.ly/WJN0). How can I make it so with the segue that the source view controller stays on screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - Semi-transparent modal view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902059/ios-semi-transparent-modal-view-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Well, found the solution. In those duplicates people state it cannot be done except when you use a screenshot as "background".

But setting this:

```
source.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

on the source controller seems to work. Then it does not disappear.