# Objective-C Modal View Controller with Transparent Background

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I wanted to create a modal View Controller that would have a transparent background but when I tried setting the alpha of the background to 0.5 it just made the view behind it completely black. This is because the background views are being removed after the transition.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
[self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
[self setDefinesPresentationContext:YES];
```

**Then presenting View Controller Code**

```
SecondViewController *alertView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:alertView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**please look at the link**
[image/linke.gif](http://b2cloud.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/invisibleBGModal1.gif)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - Semi-transparent modal view controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902059/ios-semi-transparent-modal-view-controller)

Comment: exactly @JamesP ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the action of the button in the `firstViewController` to change the view controller and present a new class `secondViewController`

```
  secondViewController *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];

    VC.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1f];
    VC.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:VC animated:NO completion:nil];
```