# Transparent ViewController to See Parent Below?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, transparency

I would like to modally add a view controller with a transparent background, so the parent view controller beneath can be seen. (This is in an app for iPhone, not for iPad.)

I have tried this:

```
TextFieldViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TextFieldVC"];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Without luck and given the view controller a clear color background. My view controller is in a storyboard if that changes anything.

Comment: This worked for me. I hope it will work for you too [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37871961/6477147)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@Josh Kahane 
set the view controller that will present the transparent view controller with this code at the `-ViewDidLoad`
and be sure to set the alpha channel of the `UIViewController` View to be lower then 1.

Code:

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but I've tried this and my view just has a black background, no transparency.

Comment: man i am using this code to my augmented reality... again, write your mail i will send you an demo.

Comment: Well, after further investigating, if I do `self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;` then it works and my view is transparent. However it stops it from animating, any ideas?

Comment: it will animate only the Dismiss part...
you didn't mention your working with navigation controller

Comment: I'm using MFSideMenu and assign my navigationController as the centerViewController and another UIViewController as the leftViewController. I tried assigning this value to self.window.rootviewcontroller in the appDelegate and also to self.menuContrainerViewController before I call presentViewController. Still black background!

Comment: strangely enough, if I do self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet in the viewDidLoad of the modally presented controller, it worked!

Answer (score 7):

I have been searching for the solution. Now thanks to iOS 8. They has introduced couple of new modalPresentationStyle. one among them is UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext. Used the same to solve the this issue.

```
viewcontroller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness and having it up-to-date, I am also adding the solution for Swift:

**either**

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
```

being - *A presentation style where the content is displayed over only the presenting view controller’s content.*

**or**

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
```

being - *A presentation style where the content is displayed over only the parent view controller’s content. The views beneath the presented content are not removed from the view hierarchy when the presentation finishes. So if the presented view controller does not fill the screen with opaque content, the underlying content shows through.*

Depending on the requirements and circumstances for the presentation.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible although there are a bunch of steps which can be easily forgotten. After struggling with myself to get this working for 4 hours  I came up with the following solution.

**1 - Create a View Controller like any other.**

*Header file*

```
#import "DDBaseViewController.h"

@interface DDHomeSearchLoadingViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

*Implementation file*

```
#import "DDHomeSearchLoadingViewController.h"

@interface DDHomeSearchLoadingViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityMonitor;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *modalView;

@end

@implementation DDHomeSearchLoadingViewController

#pragma mark - UIViewController lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self setupUI];
}

-(void) setupUI
{
    [self makeRoundedCorner:self.modalView AndCornerRadius:6.0f];
    [self.activityMonitor startAnimating];

}

-(void) makeRoundedCorner:(UIView*) view AndCornerRadius:(float) cornerRadius
{
    [view.layer setCornerRadius:cornerRadius];
    [view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
}

@end
```

**2 - Set your container view background color as ClearColor**

[image]

**3 - Add a UIView which will be presented like an overlay**

[image]

**4 - Add a UIView which will be presented like a Dialog Box over the overlay UIView**

***Make sure it's outside the overlay view when you add/move it. For some reason when you move it using the mouse it adds to overlay UIView automatically. ( Freaking annoying to be honest )***

[image]

**5 - Set the Storyboard ID for the View you've created**

[image]

**6 - Finally add this piece of code wherever you wan't call it ( Assuming it's a UiViewController too )**

```
DDHomeSearchLoadingViewController* ddHomeSearchLoadingViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DDHomeSearchLoadingViewController"];
self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:ddHomeSearchLoadingViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I hope it helps you guys out

Cheers

Comment: one+ I take screen shot and apply blur effect it looks better I guess :D

Answer (score 2):

Answer for Swift 5.

**TransparentViewController**

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

**PresentingViewController**

```
let viewController = TransparentViewController()
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
navigationController.present(viewController, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 -

Try `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen`

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExampleViewController") as! ExampleViewController
vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ChooseController *sec = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller"];
sec.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
sec.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:sec animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Note: Present controller superview alpha value must be below 1 like 0.5 alpha like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can make changes in storyboard just by doing below options and also reducing parental view opacity. Using Storyboard: No need to write any code to achieve this

[image]

Answer (score -2):

When you modally present a view controller the , it goes on the stack which in turn hides the view controller below it. So all you can do is to present a transparent view with animation similar to modally presenting a view controller.

Comment: So I can't achieve this modally? Then how do you suggest? Just adding the view as a subview?

Comment: yes... you can still have the view controller if that's what are you concerned about and add its view as subview with some animation.