# Presenting a view controller with transparency and animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uiviewcontroller, transparency

I'm setting `self.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;` in my Application Delegate so that I can present a view controller and have the view be transparent (see this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587681/how-to-use-presentmodalviewcontroller-to-create-a-transparent-view)).

This works great, only remark is that I'm not able to animate when the view controller is presented. Has anyone gotten this to work? If not, what other options do I have?

The view controller I'm presenting is a "walkthrough" that consists of a `UIScrollView` and `UIPageControl` that is supposed to "hover" over the interface so you can see the background of it slightly at the edges.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];

// Set the root VC modal presentation style
appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

WalkthroughViewController *walkthroughVC = [[WalkthroughViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:walkthroughVC animated:NO completion:nil];

// Manually animate the view
walkthroughVC.view.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
       walkthroughVC.view.alpha = 1;
}];

// Reset root VC modal presentation style 
appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
```

Comment: This is useful for me too when I'm calling back from AppDelegate (for example Twitter authentication callback), and presenting transparent view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a containment view that exists in the base view controller. Instead of presenting a modal, animate the positioning of the containment view up to simulate a modal presentation.

For example...

```
TransparentViewController *viewController = [[TransparentViewController alloc] init];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480);
self.containmnetView = viewController.view;
```

To present do this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    self.containmentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
}];
```

I hope this helps.