# ios status bar with strange behaviour

Tags: ios, statusbar, navigationcontroller

Using iOS-9.2 and Swift-2.1:

Getting back to my rootViewController using the below code, unfortunately leads to a very strange behaviour of the **status-bar** of my App !

```
    static func returnToRootViewController(sender: AnyObject) {

    let initialscene = sender.storyboard?!.instantiateInitialViewController()
    for _ in sender.view!!.window!.subviews {

        sender.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    sender.view!!.window!.rootViewController = initialscene
    }
```

The two images below show the status bar in its normal condition (i.e. left image) and after returning by above returnToRootViewController-Code (i.e right image with strange coloring) !

Prior to applying the above code, the navigation-controller was navigated to severeal modal popovers....

Any help on this appreciated !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're dismissing the same viewcontroller several times. Calling `dismissViewController` will only dismiss the one presented by the sender, not the several underneath it (I'm assuming `sender` is the topmost one)

From this answer, it sounds like you might be able to dismiss all of them just by dismissing the first one presented by your `rootViewController`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23566262/78496

Comment: Hmm, I had before only: "self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)" - but this went back just one ViewController instead of going to the rootViewController. Any idea on how to get to rootViewController without the status-bar problem ?

Comment: By the way, I am in the middle of a pageViewController - trying there to attempt to go back to the rootViewController...