# Present 2 viewcontrollers but only one transition

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to push from a View Controller "A", a second ViewController "B" (with navigation bar) which should show a third modal ViewController "C", which shows a countdown and dismisses itself, to finally show "B".

I would like "C" to be presented modally, without "B" being seen, and when it gets dismissed, "B" should already be there.

I've been looking at this posts:

- [Present multiple modal view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724166/present-multiple-modal-view-controllers)
- [Presenting a view controller with transparency and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791405/presenting-a-view-controller-with-transparency-and-animation/15794051#15794051)

But since I need "B" to be pushed (not modal) I can't use `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext`

I have also tried to do this: [How to push two view controllers but animate transition only for the second one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857222/how-to-push-two-view-controllers-but-animate-transition-only-for-the-second-one)

And it's almost what I want, but I'd like "C" to be presented in a modal style, such as cover vertical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally ended up doing a mix with these two:

- [How to push two view controllers but animate transition only for the second one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28464115/3708095)

  ```
  NSMutableArray *controllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

  MyCViewController *vcC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:IDENTIFIER_VC];
  MyBViewController *vcB = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:IDENTIFIER_VC];

  [controllers addObject:vcC];
  [controllers addObject:vcB];

  self.navigationController.delegate = vcB;
  [self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:YES];
  ```
- https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/view-controller-transitions/

In vcB:

```
    -(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
    {
        if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush || operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop) {
            MyAnimator *animator = [[MyAnimator alloc] init];
            animator.presenting = (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush);
            return animator;
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

In MyAnimator.m:

```
-(NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    return 0.4;
}

-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];

    CGRect currentFrame = toViewController.view.frame;
    CGRect toFrameInitial = self.presenting ? CGRectOffset(currentFrame, 0, CGRectGetHeight(currentFrame)) : CGRectOffset(currentFrame, 0, -CGRectGetHeight(currentFrame));
    CGRect fromFrameFinal = self.presenting ? CGRectOffset(currentFrame, 0, -CGRectGetHeight(currentFrame)) : CGRectOffset(currentFrame, 0,   CGRectGetHeight(currentFrame));

    toViewController.view.frame = toFrameInitial;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self    transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        toViewController.view.frame = currentFrame;
        fromViewController.view.frame = fromFrameFinal;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}
```