# Modal transition - One of the views is seemingly getting deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my app, I do a search asynchronously. When that completes my mapViewController with pins for the locations is displayed. 2 seconds after that, I do a modal transition over to a listViewController. I set the backgroundcolor like this:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.65];
```

Making it possible to see the map behind it.

The problem is this: Less then a second after the listView appears you can see the map in the background for a second before it goes away. What I can see in the background now, is the mainViewController the app starts with.

it looks like this:

[image]

Less than a second later:

[image]

Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is still transparent, but once your modal controller is at the top of the stack, the view behind it is hidden.

Try using :

```
yourController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[yourController present...];
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work : / Do you want to see the code?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587681/how-to-use-presentmodalviewcontroller-to-create-a-transparent-view it will help you

Comment: that post really helped. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
This code seems to work. I hope it will help. 

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    MKMapView *mapView = [MKMapView new];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    mapView.frame = self.view.bounds;

    UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [UITapGestureRecognizer new];
    [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(displayTransparentVC)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

-(void)displayTransparentVC
{
    UIViewController *vc = [TransparentViewController new];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```